# List of Gmail API Standard Error Responses

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm trying to find a list of standard gmail api error codes. Is there DoubleClick search API here: [Standard Error Responses](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-search/v2/standard-error-responses).

How about for Gmail? And will the response codes change? If I see a specific error is returned for ex with 409, can I hardcode 409 in my application?

Thanks,

MT

Answer (score 0):

It should be safe to hardcode them, They have not changed for a long time.

Here are some quota-related error codes
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota